# g++: cannot find -lnotify

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

**Trying to compile via:**

```
g++ -Wall -W main.cpp -o HelloWorldCPP -lcurl -lnotify
```

**Resulting in:**

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnotify
```

**But the library is present:**

```
$ ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep notify

libnotify.so.4 -> libnotify.so.4.0.0

libnotify.so.4.0.0
```

**The files of libcurl (which I also include via -lcurl) are in that same directory and those can be linked without problems. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Try running `file` on libnotify.so.4.0.0. Check the architecture (32- vs 64-bit)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the result is: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=bc29207f80a6b64aec329dd8397df57672ee132e, stripped

Comment: Oh, right, that's not the problem. The problem is you need a symlink from `libnotify.so` to `libnotify.so.4`. This symlink is usually part of the "-dev" or "-devel" package for the library.

Comment: I think I might be on the right track with this: the curl library has an archive file, the notify library doesn't. Maybe -l<libraryname> is trying to fetch archives ...

Comment: Tried that symlink idea, doesn't solve it: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu $ sudo ln -s libnotify.so.4 libnotify.so

Comment: Find the corresponding symlink for libcurl.so -> libcurl-XXX.so.N. Might be in a different directory... The static and dynamic linkers do not necessarily have the same search path

Comment: Ok maybe that symlink actually IS the right idea. In this case everything works: -lnotify set, symlink set, NO include (no notify code in program). In this case I get a library-find-error: -lnotify set, symlink DELETED, NO include (no notify code in program). So you should assume that the symlink solves the issue. BUT as soon as I try to include via #include <notify/notify.h> he says that he cannot find notify.h!

Comment: Which I find by the way kind of logical because there is a .h file for the curl library (which works) in /usr/include/curl/curl.h, but there is no notify.h file on the whole system. But how do I use the library if only the .so files exist? And why would that even be the case in the first place? (It's a system default, I have not deleted the .h file)

Comment: You need to install the "dev" or "devel" version of libnotify for your system. That will include both the notify.h header and the .so symlink.